# Retrieve user profile data from all of a user's friends using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I searched several examples on the web and still need some help after researching. 
I have 2 tables: users and friends.

the users table has columns:

- id bigint(20)UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
- username varchar(50)
- profile_picture varchar(200)
- status varchar(20)
- status_message varchar(200)

the friends table has columns:

- id bigint(20) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
- initiator_user_id bigint(20)
- friend_user_id bigint(20)

I want to be able to get the username, profile_picture, status, status_message from all users who are friends (friend_user_id) of a specified user (initiator_user_id). After researching I believed this is done with a union.

I have tried the query below but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT friend_user_id 
FROM friends
WHERE initiator_user_id = 1001 //gets all the id's of the friends of user 1001
UNION All
SELECT profile_picture, status, status_message, username from users
WHERE friend_user_id = id //gets all the profile data of user's profiles that are friends of user 1001
```

What I need is for the friends data to be displayed for all friends:

- id bigint(20)UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT
- username varchar(50)
- profile_picture varchar(200)
- status varchar(20)
- status_message varchar(200)

My questions:

- Does anything need to be changed regarding the tables (any foreign key constraints...etc.)?
- What do I need to change to make this example work?

Comment: No, it's not done using a UNION. It's done using a JOIN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a simple INNER JOIN:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users AS u
INNER JOIN friends AS f ON f.friend_user_id = u.id
WHERE f.initiator_user_id = 1001
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked perfectly. Now the only thing I don't understand is why developers add foreign key constraints and things of that matter. Is there an advantage to adding constraints of that type?

Comment: It allows the database to ensure that the data is correct. If there's a bug in the code that tries to create a friend pointing to a nonexistent user, the database will report an error. This is called _referential integrity_.